# What are the names of these connectors in a schematic: an 8 pin connector and one labeled BU-BNC?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

1. I am designing a PCB Schematic. I need to find the following two components. Could anyone please tell me which components are these?

   - 8 pin labeled "X1":
     [image: schematic image of first component to identify]
   - BU-BNC labeld "X4" (I know the resistor and the GND, but I don't know the name of the connector.):
     [image: schematic image of second component to identify]
2. Also, I am making a circuit with 3 multiplexers, so the idea is to have the same VCC in all three of them. I added the VCC for one and copied it to the other two. Will the system automatically figure out that it is the same and connect the symbols together as a single network when I design the trace, or will I have to add some other component? The PCB I am referring to has this arrow, but I'm not sure:
   [image]

Comment: These are schematic symbols and not specific connectors. They can designate whatever the schematic designer meant them to designate.  But the X4 one has "BNC" annotation, which might be the connector type.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell from a schematic. X4-1 seems to be a BNC connector, but X1 is some type of multi-pin connector. Other than that, there is no way of knowing. You may be able to right click it and select "Attributes" to see what the part number is. The arrow just denotes a connection to the 12V rail; it is not a connector.

Comment: A CAD system will consider all wires with the same net name to be connected together.

Comment: Open the relevant library in EAGLE and post the corresponding package along with all annotation, please

Answer (score 1):

X1 can be anything with 8 pins - it's a generic symbol.

BU-BNC is short for *BNC Buchse* in German, and means a BNC connector. It's probably a symbol that has some BNC-specific footprints associated with it. The convention used to draw that symbol is probably from the western European engineering tradition. Coaxial connectors are also drawn with a full circle in other traditions.

Answer (score 0):

Those supply symbols with arrows usually foster a so called "supply" pin in EAGLE. If you connect such a supply pin to any other pins in a schematic it enforces membership of all connected wires and pins in a net with the same name as the supply symbol. Hence when switching to the layout all corresponding components in junction with supply pins of the same name in the schematic will be connected with yellow airwires.

There is no physical representation of the supply pin in the layout. It is only a logical naming automatism. Beware when connecting more than one different supply pin to a net, then this mechanism will fail and you will get warnings when executing the ERC.

Beware also, that you should check the library of the supply pin, if this is really a supply pin (check the pin function within the library) otherwis it won't work as described.